# C program which returns the sum of the digits of an integer

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

int sum=0, prod=1, a, b;

printf("Enter a number: \n");

scanf("%d",&a);

while (a!=0)

sum = sum + a%10;
    a = a/10;

while (b!=0)

prod = prod + b%10;
    b = b/10;


printf("Sum=%d\nProd=%d\n", sum, prod);


return 0;
}
```

This C program returns the sum and product of the digits of a given integer, but i want someone to break it down for me, and also when i ran it, it doesn't work, so can someone correct me, please.

Comment: `a % 10` extracts the final digit, `a / 10` removes the final digit. The program is defective due to missing braces to specify the loop body. C ain't Python you know.

Comment: This program doesn't work because of lack of brackets.

Comment: It seems it's code by someone else than you. Can you ask them to explain it? If not, try to make sense of it yourself, [edit] your question to document what you understand and where you have difficulties (and how you tried to research them). That way, it can become a good SO question instead of the current "do my work for me," which is not a good fit here.

Comment: What do you mean with "and it works fine"? This code does not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

`%` is the modulus operation, i.e. it gives you the reminder of the division by the divisor. In your case the operation `% 10` effectively returns the last digit of the number. You sum this digit to the `prod` variable which represents the total sum of digits. Once you have summed the current digit you perform the next main operation `/ 10` which is integer divison and just removes the last digit of the number.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very badly indented and necessary block delimiters `{}` are missing. Also `b` is not initialized and you compute the sum, not the product of the digits.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, sum, prod, a, b;

    printf("Enter a number: \n");

    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;

    a = n;
    sum = 0;
    while (a != 0) {
        sum = sum + a % 10;
        a = a / 10;
    }

    b = n;
    prod = 1;
    while (b != 0) {
        prod = prod * (b % 10);
        b = b / 10;
    }

    printf("Sum=%d\nProd=%d\n", sum, prod);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Name: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score. You can upvote it once you have enough reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

As you're reading the number from the user, read a string.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[999];
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) { // read a string rather than scanf an integer
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0; // remove trailing newline
        char *p = buf;
        int invalidflag = (*p == 0);
        unsigned sum = 0;
        unsigned product = 1;
        while (*p) {
            if (isdigit((unsigned char)*p)) {
                sum += *p - '0';
                product *= *p - '0';
            } else {
                invalidflag = 1;
                break;
            }
            p++;
        }
        if (invalidflag) {
            printf("input = \"%s\" ==> INVALID INPUT\n", buf);
        } else {
            printf("input = \"%s\"; sum = %d; product = %d\n", buf, sum, product);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[See ideone.com/ZLkOfJ](https://ideone.com/ZLkOfJ)